# In Spring, we do we actually need DataSourceTransactionManager and TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I've been building a web backend using Spring, and so far the way I've used to connect to database is just by configuring the DriverManagerDataSource bean:

```
@Bean()
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSourceManager = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSourceManager.setDriverClassName(...);
        dataSourceManager.setUrl(...);
        dataSourceManager.setUsername(...);
        dataSourceManager.setPassword(...);
        return dataSourceManager;
    }
```

It has been working fine for me.

But I've also seen people configuring DataSourceTransactionManager and TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy (especially in this guide: http://www.baeldung.com/jooq-with-spring).

I'm wondering under what circumstances do we need these two classes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Start in [this chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction) from the Spring documentation, if you have a real and specific question not covered there, post a new question.

Comment: I will check that out. Thanks!

Comment: i would love to see a simple answear for this question. Documentions can be confusing.